# Entity Framework - Saving foreign key referring to new record

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, foreign-key-relationship, savechanges

I have a problem saving my data in Entity Framework.

I have done a function that overrides the saveChanges of my dbContext, because I use it to set some audit data and do other stuff. In one case I have a big trouble.

I have to insert, for each new record, some records in another table, referring to the new with a foreign key. If the new record is only one, it is all ok. But if the record are 2 or more, I get errors.

I have a for, looping on all the new records, in this way:

```
var addedAuditedEntities = ChangeTracker.Entries()
    .Where(p => p.State == EntityState.Added)
    .Select(p => p.Entity);

foreach (var added in addedAuditedEntities)
{
    .....
}
```

I write my attempts.

1) in this way, it gives error at the second new record, saying that there is already an unique data in the tab TabAssVeicoliTerminali (it is a table with an unique index on the couple IDTER-IDTEV), I think because it inserts temporary all records with IDTEV = 0

```
else if (added.GetType() == typeof(TabTessereVeicoli))
{
    TabTessereVeicoli i = (TabTessereVeicoli)added;
    i.DATA_INS = now;
    i.USER_INS = mdlImpostazioni.p.UserName;
    var listaterV = new List<TabAssVeicoliTerminali>();
    foreach (var ter in MainWindow.dbContext.TabTerminali) 
    {
        var tt = new TabAssVeicoliTerminali();
        tt.MODIFICATO = true;
        tt.ABILITATO = true;
        tt.IDTER = ter.ID;
        tt.IDTEV = i.ID;
        tt.DATA_INS = now;
        tt.USER_INS = mdlImpostazioni.p.UserName;
        listaterV.Add(tt);
    }
    MainWindow.dbContext.BulkInsert(listaterV);
}
```

2) So, I tried to save before, to try to set the ID of the new record (it is autoincremental id) and use something != 0 in the IDTEV foreign key. But, it saves all, also the other new records. So, it saves correctly the fk in other table, but only for the first new record:

```
else if (added.GetType() == typeof(TabTessereVeicoli))
{
    TabTessereVeicoli i = (TabTessereVeicoli)added;
    i.DATA_INS = now;
    i.USER_INS = mdlImpostazioni.p.UserName;
    var listaterV = new List<TabAssVeicoliTerminali>();
    base.SaveChanges();
    foreach (var ter in MainWindow.dbContext.TabTerminali) 
    {
        var tt = new TabAssVeicoliTerminali();
        tt.MODIFICATO = true;
        tt.ABILITATO = true;
        tt.IDTER = ter.ID;
        tt.IDTEV = i.ID;
        tt.DATA_INS = now;
        tt.USER_INS = mdlImpostazioni.p.UserName;
        listaterV.Add(tt);
    }
    MainWindow.dbContext.BulkInsert(listaterV);
}
```

3) I have also tried without the BulkInsert, but I get the same results.

How can I reach my goal?

Comment: Why does Entity Framework Reinsert Existing Objects into My Database? msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn166926.aspx

Comment: @Colin already read it, but it didn't helped me...

Comment: Did you check the pair: ter.ID and i.ID? If i.ID was 0, you would not get unique constraint problem, because ter.ID would give you different value.

Comment: in the debug, I see i.ID = 0... what do you mean? I think the i.ID = 0 is the problem, because, in the second loop, it inserts again the same couples, with i.ID = 0 and ter.ID as before. But it needs to be i.ID = x, then x + 1, then x + 2...

Comment: If i.ID = 0 then that implies you have added i to the context but you have not saved the changes to the database. You can not add related records until after you have saved parent records unless you add them to the navigation property collection of the parent record. Otherwise EF cannot determine which entity/record they are related to.

Comment: Ok, I know this. You can see that one of my attempts is to save after I add the "master record for the fk relationship". In this way it works, but only for the first of the new records, because it save in one code-row all, also the other new records. Do you understand my trobule now?

Comment: @BenRobinson you wrote "...unless you add them to the navigation property collection of the parent record...". What do you mean? If I do this, will the i.ID be != 0? How?

Comment: I have no idea what your entities look like but broadly speaking you do `ParentEntity.Children.Add(childEntity);` where `ParentEntity.Children` is your navigation property for your many to one relationship.

Comment: @BenRobinson what will be changing in this way? Can I use it with the bulk insert?

Comment: @BenRobinson ok, it works now, but how can I use it with the bulk insert? Following your hint, I have commented the bulk part, but I need it, because I can insert a lot of data in the same moment.

Comment: I think if you want to do a bulk insert then you will have to save `i` (i.e. call `DbContext.SaveChanges`) before creating then `TabAssVeicoliTerminali` entities. This way `i.Id` will be updated with the PK value that was generated on the DB insert.

Comment: @BenRobinson I can't, this is what I was saying before. If I do this with base.saveChamges, it saves all the new records at once, also the other new parent records, that are still to process (and so it works well only for the first new record). If I do dbContext.saveChanges, it enters in a infinite loop.

Comment: @BenRobinson I have added an answer to the question. There is also the new code. Still not bulkInsert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from the hint of Ben Robinson in the comments of this question, I have found a solution.

It works, but it stil is the "perfect solution", because to do it, I had to comment the part of the bulk insert, so it is a bit slow with a lot of new records.

Anyway, the code I have posted in the question, is now:

```
else if (added.GetType() == typeof(TabTessereVeicoli))
{
    TabTessereVeicoli i = (TabTessereVeicoli)added;
    i.DATA_INS = now;
    i.USER_INS = mdlImpostazioni.p.UserName;
    var listaterV = new List<TabAssVeicoliTerminali>();
    foreach (var ter in MainWindow.dbContext.TabTerminali) 
    {
        var tt = new TabAssVeicoliTerminali();

        tt.MODIFICATO = true;
        tt.ABILITATO = true;
        tt.IDTER = ter.ID;
        tt.IDTEV = i.ID;
        tt.DATA_INS = now;
        tt.USER_INS = mdlImpostazioni.p.UserName;
        //listaterV.Add(tt);
        i.TabAssVeicoliTerminali.Add(tt);
    }
    //MainWindow.dbContext.BulkInsert(listaterV);
}
```

Let me know if you know how can I reach my goal using also the bulkInsert!